# Atomic Upsert MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

What is the best method to atomically update a row if exists, else insert a new row into an table?

e.g. say we have this example below.

```
CREATE TABLE Test(
id integer,
val varchar(255)
)

DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `TestUpsert` $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `TestUpsert` (in value1 varchar(255), in id1 int)
BEGIN
    IF EXISTS(Select 1 from Test where id=id1) THEN
        UPDATE Test set val  = value1 where id = id1;
    ELSE
        insert into Test(id, val) VALUES (id1, value1);
    END IF;

END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

What changes can we make to TestUpsert to make it atomic?

Comment: This is clearly MySQL, so I removed the T-SQL tag.

Answer (score 1):

Use `on duplicate key update`:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `TestUpsert` (
    in in_value varchar(255),
    in in_id int
)
BEGIN
    insert into test(id, val)
        values (in_id, in_val)
        on duplicate key update val = in_val;
END $$
```

I should add that for this to work, `test.id` has to be declared as the primary key or unique.

Comment: What if my where statement is not for a pk

Comment: @Max . . . It should be unique; otherwise, how to do you know which row to update?

Comment: e.g. We could have compound keys - e.g.CREATE TABLE Test(
id integer,
id2 integer,
val varchar(255)
)

Then we would be updating val on id and id2.

Comment: @Max . . . This identifies a unique row using available primary keys and unique indexes.  The number of keys doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you read about [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html).

See my lengthy answer about this statement here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/548570/20860